# Texturing problem

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I have a problem here with textures. All the models you see are textured, except for the roof and floor. Those look grey, and when I textures them, they show only the main color of the texture instead of the detail in the textures. For example when I try to apply a red bricks texture, it takes the basic colour, red, but doesn't show the white color in the mortar lines between the bricks.

Here is how it appears in the world in Unity3D, after putting the texture:

[image: how it looks in unity3d world]

Here is how it appears Blender

[image: how it looks in blender]

Comment: 1st picture is the problem, second one is how it looks in blender

Comment: You probably have the image texture UV mapped correctly, which is why it works in the viewport, but you don't have the image node used as a colour input into your shader node (Diffuse, etc).

Comment: Fastest way for us to figure it out is if you can post the blend file.

Comment: Seems the problem here is in Unity, not Blender.